# How to get values from EditText to pass into asyntask that is at another class?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to do a update profile where I get my values from the EditProfile.java and displaying it on another page called ConfirmEdit.java to update the login record in database when user press the confirm button. I used intent putExtra to pass values from one class to another but have not been able to do so here.

As my code, I passed three parameters namely, username, name and handphone. But, when i did a print at ConfirmEdit.java, only username was printed out.

Kindly help thanks!

The codes are below:

EditProfile.java

```
public class EditProfile extends Activity {

    Button backbtn, updatebtn;
    String user, name_entered, username_returned, registered_name;
    String handphone_no;
    String updated_username;
    EditText username, password_entered, name, handphone;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = url;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editprofile);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            user = extras.getString("username");
        }

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_signup);
        password_entered = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        handphone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.handphone);
        backbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
        updatebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updatebtn);


        new AttemptLogin().execute(user);

        updatebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                registered_name = name.getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(EditProfile.this, ConfirmEdit.class);
                i.putExtra("registered_name", registered_name);
                i.putExtra("user", user);
                i.putExtra("password", password_entered.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("handphone", handphone.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);
            }
            });
                /*updated_username = name.getText().toString();
                new updateProfile().execute(updated_username, user, handphone.getText().toString() ,password_entered.getText().toString());
            }
        });*/

        backbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(EditProfile.this, AccountPage.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }




    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // here Check for success tag
            try {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("user", args[0]);
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                if (json != null) {

                    Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());

                    return json;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

            if (json != null) {
                Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this, json.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                try {
                    username_returned = json.getString("username");
                    handphone_no = json.getString("handphone");
                    name_entered = json.getString("name");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String messageString = username_returned;
                username.setText(messageString);
                String messageString2 = handphone_no;
                handphone.setText(messageString2);
                String messageString3 = name_entered;
                name.setText(messageString3);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

ConfirmEdit.java

```
public class ConfirmEdit extends Activity {

    String name, handphone, username, password;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private static final String UPDATE_PROFILE = url;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.confirmedit);

        Button updatebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cfmupdatebtn);

        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            name = extras.getString("registered_name");
            username = extras.getString("user");
            password = extras.getString("password");
            handphone = extras.getString("handphone");
        }

        String messageString = name;
        t.setText(messageString);
        String messageString1 = username;
        t1.setText(messageString1);
        String messageString2 = handphone;
        t2.setText(messageString2);



        updatebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new updateProfile().execute(name,username,handphone);
                System.out.println(name);
                System.out.println(username);
                System.out.println(handphone);

            }
        });
    }
        class updateProfile extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
            private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
            private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

            protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // here Check for success tag
                try {
                    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("name", args[0]);

                    params.put("username", args[1]);
                    params.put("handphone", args[2]);
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            UPDATE_PROFILE, "POST", params);

                    if (json != null) {

                        Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());

                        return json;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
                int success = 0;
                String message = "";

                if (json != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(ConfirmEdit.this, json.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    try {
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        message = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (success == 1) {
                        Log.d("Acknowledgement!", message);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what about make your own constructor in your Asynktask. Check my answer

Comment: Probably app is crashing. `Toast` is showing or not?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK app is NOT crashing

Answer (score 1):

Ok, having:

```
    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // here Check for success tag
        try {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("user", args[0]);
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            if (json != null) {

                Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());

                return json;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

        if (json != null) {
            Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this, json.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                username_returned = json.getString("username");
                handphone_no = json.getString("handphone");
                name_entered = json.getString("name");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String messageString = username_returned;
            username.setText(messageString);
            String messageString2 = handphone_no;
            handphone.setText(messageString2);
            String messageString3 = name_entered;
            name.setText(messageString3);
        }
    }
}
```

you could add some custom and own constructor, as this:

```
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
String username, password, handphone, name;  

public AttemptLogin(String _username, String _password, String  _handphone, String _name){

    this.username = _username;
    this.password = _password;
    this.handphone = _handphone;
    this.name = _name;

}
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // here Check for success tag
        try {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("user", args[0]);
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            if (json != null) {

                Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());

                return json;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

        if (json != null) {
            Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this, json.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                username_returned = json.getString("username");
                handphone_no = json.getString("handphone");
                name_entered = json.getString("name");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String messageString = username_returned;
            username.setText(messageString);
            String messageString2 = handphone_no;
            handphone.setText(messageString2);
            String messageString3 = name_entered;
            name.setText(messageString3);
        }
    }
}
```

So then you should change this line:

```
new AttemptLogin().execute(user);
```

to this:

```
new AttemptLogin(username, password, handphone, name).execute();
```

and that is a best way to handle that.

Hope that helps. Regards

**EDIT**
If you want to send your TextView/EditText or some control, you just have to change your constructor, as this:

```
    EditText username, password, handphone, name;  

public AttemptLogin(EditText _username, EditText _password, EditText  _handphone, EditText _name){

    this.username = _username;
    this.password = _password;
    this.handphone = _handphone;
    this.name = _name;

}
```

And obviously when you process your data, you have to extract the string of that, so i think is the same thing. To get the String of an EditText/TextView is:

```
yourEditText.getText().toString();
```

Comment: But what I am trying to do is EditProfile which have the EditView, the values that are typed in to be passed into ConfirmEdit so I could run the UpdateProfile() to update the db values.. I am using putextra methods but it's not working. I not sure if your solution tackles that.

Comment: Ok so how do i get the values from ConfirmEdit.java once the constructor is set up?

Comment: you could send in the postExecute method as bundle/extra data to your intent, or save in sharedPreferences, or save en Sqlite. Try to use sharedPreferences.